# Восстановление пароля

Tags: запрос, php, база-данных, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, делаю форму восстановления пароля, и казалось бы большую часть сделал, но возникли трудности, т.к. можно сказать еще новичок.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне вытащить значение переменной $mail из первой функции, в которую попадает e-mail, вводимый пользователем для восстановления пароля, чтобы поменять пароль тому пользователю, у которого поле email в БД равнялось переменной mail?

```
function restore_pass() {
    $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
    $query = "SELECT email FROM customers WHERE email = '$mail'";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['restore']['res'] = "<div class='success'><p><b>Письмо для восстановления пароля отправлено Вам на почту.</b></p></div>";
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $to = $row['email'];
        $from = "test@test.ru";
        $tema   = "=?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode("Восстановление пароля") . "?=";
        $header = "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $header .= "From: <" . $from . ">\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $msg  = "Для создания нового пароля кликните по ссылке:<br><br><a href='".PATH."?view=new_pass'>Задать новый пароль</a>";
        @mail($to, $tema, $msg, $header);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['restore']['res'] = "<div class='error'><p><b>Такого e-mail не существует!</b></p></div>";;
    }
}
```

---

```
function new_pass($mail) {
    $pass = trim($_POST['newpass']);
    $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
    $query = "SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE email = '$mail'";
    exit($query);
}
```

Вторую функцию еще не дописал, т.к. не пойму как мне вытащить переменную $mail. Нужна ли вообще вторая функция или можно обойтись в одной?

p.s. Насчет уязвимостей и хэширования пароля не ругайтесь, это я потом сделаю.

---

**Добавил return $to, дописал вторую функцию, но выдает ошибку, т.к. в поле email кажется попадает пустое значение:**

---

Немного переписал, добавил GET параметр, и в первой функции в отправляемое письмо (в ссылку добавил id пользователя).

```
function new_pass() {
    $pass = trim($_POST['newpass']);
    if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    }
    $query = "UPDATE customers SET password = '$pass' WHERE customer_id = $user_id";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['new_pass']['res'] = "<div class='success'><p><b>Вы создали новый пароль.</b></p></div>";
    }
}
```

Пароль в БД меняется, но почему-то перестает пускать на сайт под новым паролем (ведь это не связано с тем, что я его еще не обрабатывал функцией md5.. оказалось связано, т.к. я забыл что при авторизации я обрабатываю пароль), есть ли какие-либо минусы и уязвимости в таком способе с передачей GET-параметра?

Comment: ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ $_POST и другие глобальные переменные внутри функций есть зло!!!

Comment: Почему? А как же тогда быть?

Comment: $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);  

Попробуйте передать `1' OR id>'0` и у Вас получится запрос
    
    $query = "SELECT email FROM customers WHERE email = '1' OR id>'0'";

почитайте про mysql_real_escape_string и экранирование параметров


По теме, не совсем понятно, что значит "вытащить". Может вы имеете ввиду 

   ....
   @mail($to, $tema, $msg, $header);
   return $to;
   ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "вытащить". Может вы имеете ввиду вернуть ее из функции, тогда вот так

```
function restore_pass() {
   ....
   @mail($to, $tema, $msg, $header);
   return $to;
   ....
}

$mailTo = restore_pass();
```

Comment: >т.к. в поле email кажется попадает пустое значение

Так проверьте, чтобы быть уверенным. 


     >есть ли какие-либо минусы и уязвимости в таком способе с передачей GET-параметра

Без обработки этих параметров не важно, `get` или `post` уязвимость одна и та же. передаем в `user_id` `1 or customer_id >0` и получаем `WHERE customer_id = 1 or customer_id>0` как итог у всех один и тот же пароль. Заходим под админом с новым паролем.